# why do Syntax error (python) doesn't work?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql, except

I want to print a message in case the user made a mistake while writing the code but it doesnt work I also tried to add NameError exception, it only works if I raise an exception.Thank you for helping.

`

```
def  cncours(nvcours,num_cours):
  try :
    sql="Update cours set nomC=%s where num_cours=%s"
    result=cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.execute(sql,(nvcours,num_cours))
    print("Operation Done.")
  except TypeError:
    print("Plz put the name between quotes")

 `
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error traceback. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Each DB implementation (MySQL, sqlite,...) may raise their particular exceptions. So instead of catching a general exceptions, you may catch errors depending on the specific DB, then on the particular type (e.g. SyntaxError). I suggest to provoque a syntax error on your SQL statement then see what type is (e.g. errorcode or exception type) then catch it.

For instance, the MySQL connector raises [error numbers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-errors-error.html):

```
import mysql.connector as cn
try:
  #...
except cn.Error as err:
  print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))
  if err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_TABLE_ERROR:  #
```

Here are some [MySQL Error Code Ranges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-message-components.html#error-code-ranges)

If you are using MySQLdb:

```
import MySQLdb
try:
    #...
    cursor.execute(sql)
    res = cursor.fetchone()
    # ...
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print "MySQLdb.Error: {}".format(e.args)
```

Depending on your schema (column types) and the type from the input variable, you may use:

```
sql="Update cours set nomC='%s' where num_cours=%s"  # Added quotes on the first replacement
```

Besides what you are asking, I think that the command order is inverted.

```
sql="Update cours set nomC=%s where num_cours=%s"
cursor.execute(sql,(nvcours,num_cours))  # First
result=cursor.fetchone()                 # Second
print("Operation Done.")
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm

```
# execute SQL query using execute() method.
cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
# Fetch a single row using fetchone() method.
data = cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: Thank you mr Omr you are right.I didn't notice it.But I have a problem with the Try-except it doesn't work when I need it..

Comment: What is the error message? What type of DB are you using? What DB wrapper library are you using (i.e. what imports)?

Comment: PyMySQL// MySQL//Inno DB //Python 3.7